# Merge Pull Request Manually

Tags: git, github

So I have following situation in github.

1. I created a fresh branch from the `mainbranch` and named as `userstory1`
2. I pushed my changes in branch `userstory1` and raised a pull request to my colleague
3. He saw that folder structure was not correct so renamed my code folder in `mainbranch`. So now I have folder `mycode` on `userstory1` branch whereas on `mainbranch` its named `my-code`. My changes on branch `userstory1` are yet to be merged to `mainbranch`
4. Of course now automatic merge of my pull request is not possible on `mainbranch`

What is the best way to handle this situation? I want to use the same pull request for merging changes on branch `userstory1` to `mainbranch`

What I have thought of is to get the code from `mainbranch` onto my machine and commit it to branch `userstory1`  but not sure if same pull request can be used if I do more commits on `userstory1` branch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways First Is

checkout userstory1

```
git checkout userstory1
```

Now merge mainbranch

```
git merge --no-ff mainbranch
```

It will show you the conflict.
To see clearly type

```
git status
```

and pay attention for the files that are changed  on both side.

Now resolve the conflict manually and then type

```
git commit
```

If you want to add message it's upto you other wise it will ammend to previous one

then push the code

```
git push origin  userstory1
```

assuming origin as remote url.

No need to do anything with pull-request it will automatically updated.

Comment: you made it super easy

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve this is to update your local copy of the main branch, rebase your changes on top of this, and then push them (with `-f`) back to github.

This will update your pull request, which having been rebased on the main branch will be merge-able automatically.

[This document](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/wiki/How-to-Rebase-a-Pull-Request) seems to have a lot of good detail on the process.