# Manually merge git pull request

Tags: git, github, merge

I am confused on the proper way to manually merge a pull request, and to understand why there are different suggestions regarding it.

Suppose the simplest situation: one `master` (long-lived) branch and one single `feature` branch with several commits for which a pull request is made but which shows merge conflicts with the master branch.

GitHub says to do:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b feature origin/feature
git merge master
```

and then

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff feature
git push origin master
```

1. Why do we merge `master` into `feature` and then the reverse after that? [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351108/git-merge-two-branches-what-direction) suggests the order doesn't matter but [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644276/merging-to-branches-doesnt-matter-which-one-you-merge-into) suggests there are issues relating to the parent.
2. [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722118/merge-pull-request-manually) discusses manually merging pull requests but says you only need to merge your master branch *into* your feature branch and that's it. How is that consistent with what GitHub says?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your point 2, it doesn't say to merge the story into master because that's not what the OP wants to do.

Regarding your question. Let's assume we have this:

```
               master
 *---*----*----*
      \        
       ---*----*
               feature
```

If you merge *master* into *feature*, that will bring all the changes made into master to your feature branch. The feature branch will contain the latest changes from master *plus* the changes in the feature:

```
               master
 *---*----*----*
      \         \
       ---*----*--*
                  feature
```

*master* will thus still point to the same commit as before, but *feature* will point to a new commit, which has all the changes for both branches.

So you still need to merge back the changes from the feature to master. That's a very simple operation now, since master is an ancestor of feature. So merging is a simple *fast-forward*:

```
 *---*----*----*
      \         \
       ---*----*--*
                  feature
                  master
```

I much prefer keeping a linear history, and thus rebasing the feature branch on master before merging it into master. But your mileage may vary.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you help! It makes sense for keeping linear history but if the `feature` branch is short-lived (i.e., will be deleted after merging), is it correct to simply merge `feature` INTO `master`, resolve conflicts that arise, and then delete feature?

Comment: The problem with this answer is that github does all it's merging with the `--no-ff` option, so you get a much messier tree.